# curl with headers loop syntax issue

Tags: curl

I'm trying to do some API REST requests with the curl loop command below.
With a first list of URL (with REST request inside), this works perfectly, with a second one I get "curl: (3) Illegal characters found in URL"

```
for i in `rest_a_url_list` ; do curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Auth-Token: $token" $i ; done
```

First url list with lines like :
https://some.api.net/REST/ARESTCOMM/x/
Second list :
https://some.api.net/REST/BRESTCOMM/x/x/xxxx

I also tried to put the curl loop output in a bash script and "bash -x myfile.sh" and got also an illegal char error. But when I cat my file and copy some lines to exec it works.

Bash -x output give some simple quotes in place of doubles and place a '$' just before url
curl -D -H -X GET -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Auth-Token: $token' $'url'

I tested several times and always the result.
Perhaps onather way to achieve this but all that is starting to confuse me.
Any thoughts what wrong I am doing?

Comment: It may be a good idea to surround `$i` in quotes to prevent some possible problems. Also there could be something wrong with your list for all we know...

Comment: There might be some character that needs to be encoded specially in your JSON document. What is the failing data that causes the error?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry there was some wrongs char in my url_list file, as I sed and tr on this file previous to use it in loop.
All works fine now for me.